# Merging Pandas rows based on index (time series)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I used `Pandas` `.append()` to add columns from a number of `Pandas` `timeseries` by their index (date). However, instead of combining all data from common dates into one row, the data looks like this:

```
sve2_all.sort(inplace=True)
print sve2_all['20000101':'20000104']



Hgtot ng/l     Q l/s  DOC_mg/L  Flow_mm/day  MeHg ng/l Site  \
2000-01-01          NaN       NaN       NaN         0.18        NaN  NaN   
2000-01-01          NaN  0.613234       NaN          NaN        NaN  SVE   
2000-01-02          NaN       NaN       NaN         0.18        NaN  NaN   
2000-01-02          NaN  0.614410       NaN          NaN        NaN  SVE   
2000-01-03          NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN    2   
2000-01-03          NaN  0.617371       NaN          NaN        NaN  SVE   
2000-01-03          NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN  NaN   
2000-01-03          NaN       NaN       NaN         0.18        NaN  NaN   
2000-01-04          NaN  0.627733       NaN          NaN        NaN  SVE   
2000-01-04          NaN       NaN       NaN         0.18        NaN  NaN   

            TOC_filt.TOC  TOC_unfilt.TOC  Temp oC  pH  
2000-01-01           NaN             NaN      NaN NaN  
2000-01-01           NaN             NaN -12.6117 NaN  
2000-01-02           NaN             NaN      NaN NaN  
2000-01-02           NaN             NaN  -2.3901 NaN  
2000-01-03           NaN        8.224648      NaN NaN  
2000-01-03           NaN             NaN  -5.0064 NaN  
2000-01-03           NaN             NaN      NaN NaN  
2000-01-03           NaN             NaN      NaN NaN  
2000-01-04           NaN             NaN  -1.5868 NaN  
2000-01-04           NaN             NaN      NaN NaN  

[10 rows x 10 columns]
```

I've tried to resample this data by day using:

```
sve2_all.resample('D', how='mean')
```

And also to group by day using:

```
sve2_all.groupby(sve2_all.index.map(lambda t: t.day))
```

However, the `DataFrame` remains unchanged. How can I collapse the rows for the same date into one date? Thanks.

**Additional information:** I tried using `pd.concat()` as suggested by Joris (I had to pass 0 as the axis argument as 1 resulted in `ValueError:cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`) instead of `.append()` but the resulting `DataFrame` is the same as with `.append()`, a non-uniform non-monotonic time series. I think the index is the problem but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it, I thought that some time stamps might contain hour information while other not so I tried I've also tried using `.resample('D',how='mean')` on each `DataFrame` before using `.concat()` but it didn't make a difference.

**Solution:** Joris solution was correct, I didn't realise that `.resample()` wasn't inplace. Once the `.resample()` was assigned to a new `DataFrame` Joris' suggestion provided the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `append` method does 'append' the rows to the other dataframe, and does not merge with it based on the index labels. For that you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Using a toy example:

```
In [14]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=3))
In [15]: df1
Out[15]:
                   A         B
2000-01-01  1.532085 -1.338895
2000-01-02 -0.016784 -0.270698
2000-01-03 -1.680379  0.838287

In [16]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), columns=list('CD'), index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=3))
In [17]: df2
Out[17]:
                   C         D
2000-01-01  0.375214 -0.812558
2000-01-02 -1.099848 -0.889941
2000-01-03  1.556383  0.870608
```

`.append` will append the rows (and columns of `df2` that are not in `df1` will be added, which is the case here):

```
In [18]: df1.append(df2)
Out[18]:
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  1.532085 -1.338895       NaN       NaN
2000-01-02 -0.016784 -0.270698       NaN       NaN
2000-01-03 -1.680379  0.838287       NaN       NaN
2000-01-01       NaN       NaN  0.375214 -0.812558
2000-01-02       NaN       NaN -1.099848 -0.889941
2000-01-03       NaN       NaN  1.556383  0.870608
```

`pd.concat()` concatenates the both dataframes along one of the index axises:

```
In [19]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[19]:
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  1.532085 -1.338895  0.375214 -0.812558
2000-01-02 -0.016784 -0.270698 -1.099848 -0.889941
2000-01-03 -1.680379  0.838287  1.556383  0.870608
```

Apart from that, the `resample` should normally work.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I tried using `pd.concat()` (I had to pass 0 as the axis argument as 1 resulted in `ValueError:cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` instead of `.append()` but the resulting `DataFrame` is the same as with `.append()`, a non-uniform non-monotonic time series. I think the index is the problem but I'm not sure where to start looking, I thought that some time stamps might contain hour information while other not which is why I wanted to resample or groupby day. Do you have any suggestions/methods I could look at? Thanks again.

Comment: I've also tried using `.resample('D',how='mean')` on each `DataFrame` before using `.concat()`.

Comment: The error you get is because you have duplicate indices in one of your dataframes. And as the error says, `concat` cannot handle this. So you should remove these duplicates indices (and then the resample should be a good approach), or otherwise you could maybe use merge: `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`. But what error do you get if you first do `.resample('D')` on both dataframes and then do `concat([..], axis=1)`? Because this should normally work (with the resample, you shouldn't have the problem of the duplicate values).

Comment: BTW, you have to use `axis=1`, as `axis=0` will concatenate the two dataframes along the first axis, so concatenate the row indices, which is indeed the same as `append` (you want to concatenate the columns indices (axis=1), while matching the row indices)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what does 'duplicate indices' mean? Does it mean that df1 and df2 both have a row with exactly the same time stamp? Or does it mean that df1 (or df2) has two duplicate timestamps within itself?
To answer your question, doing `.resample` on both `DataFrames` ahead of the `concat` doesn't make a difference, I still get the `ValueError`

Comment: Yes, that last one. So that df1 or df2 (or both) have each two or more index values that are exactly the same (in your case probably the same days). And because of that, `concat` does not know how to match the indices between df1 and df2 (as there are more matches possible).

Comment: Note that resample is not inplace. So doing `df.resample('D')` is not enough, you have to reassign it: `df = df.resample('D')` (or give it another name of course, as you like)

Comment: I've try using `.merge`, it joins the `DataFrames` correctly but only for the shortest index, I have 4 `DataFrames` with the longest time series starting in 1981 and the shortest in 1993. The new `DataFrame` starts in 1993. This is not ideal but I can work around it. I'll look into dropping the duplicates and then try your originally suggested approach. Thanks!

Comment: Did you do the resample correctly? Because this really should work.

Comment: Oh gosh wow! I didn't realise that `.resample()` wasn't inplace! Everything's working perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, almost no pandas methods are inplace by default unless you specify it specifically, best to remember that